# In England & Wales, how much latitude is there in the phrase "at business premises" in VERA S.29(2C)?

Tags: england-and-wales, vehicle, statutes, parking

In the Vehicle Excise and Registration Act 1994 (as amended), [Section 29](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1994/22/section/29), Subsection 2C, an exception is made to the offence of using or keeping a vehicle which is unlicensed, "if the vehicle is kept by a motor trader or vehicle tester at business premises".

One of the DVLA's authorised private enforcement agencies took action against a vehicle in the possession of a motor trader I know, which was parked on private land, and immobilised it by clamping the wheel.

The enforcement agency cited the Finance Act 2008 as giving them the power to immobilise on private land.

In my correspondence to the DVLA, I pointed out:

> [I]t is the Vehicle Excise Duty (Immobilisation, Removal and Disposal of Vehicles) Regulations 1997 (“Immobilisation Regulations”) that grants enforcement powers to deal with offences under VERA S.29(1). It has been amended by secondary legislation in 2008 as a direct result of the Finance Act [2008] to refer to a “relevant place” and provide for a power of entry.

The vehicle was parked on private land shared by more than one business, which constitutes a parking/loading area and which must be passed through in order to access the premises rented by the motor trader. I do not know if any wayleaves or other historic agreements are in place that cover the access arrangements.

The DVLA said that since "the vehicle was parked outside of the secure area designated for use by the motor trader", the exception in VERA S.29(2C) "is not applicable on this occasion". They did not quote any publication, guidelines, legislation or case relating to their interpretation.

They did not respond to my having pointed out that:

> Enforcement is lawful only where an authorised person has “reason to believe that an offence” under VERA S.29(1) “is being committed” (Reg. 5(1) of the Immobilisation Regulations)

Whether the threshold for belief was reached may be another question, however, I would like to know suitably qualified users' opinions and/or experience with the phrase "at business premises" and how this may or may not apply in the circumstances described.

**In your interpretation, was the vehicle "at business premises"?**

**Are you aware of anything that interprets or modifies the definition of "business premises" or the word "at" as used in VERA S.29(2C)?**